# Display menu on NSTableView if a row is selected

Tags: swift, nstableview, nsmenu

I have a menu on the outlet of an NSTableView. It will show the menu when I right click on the Table View, but I don't want to show the menu if there is no row selected. How can I stop the menu from showing when I right click and there is no row selected?

I have tried the:

```
validateMenuItem
```

but it never gets called

I have tried NSMenuDelegate and its

```
func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) { }
```

and

```
func menuNeedsUpdate(_ menu: NSMenu) { }
```

but none of them return anything that I can set to DONT show menu IF...

The suggested duplicate asks to prevent displaying the contextual menu when clicking on a specific cell. This question is about preventing the menu to show when no ROW is selected.

Comment: The suggested duplicate asks to prevent displaying the contextual menu when clicking on a specific cell. This question is about preventing the menu to show when no ROW is selected.

Comment: The solution is the same. Instead of `row == self.numberOfRows - 1` check if a row is selected.

Comment: Or does "no row selected" mean not clicked on a row? I was thinking about `selectedRowIndexes`.

Comment: The table view can have a number of rows or no rows at all, the menu pops showing options for the register (row) regardless if there is even a row selected. I was looking to verify that a row is selected before displaying the menu, and not allowing the menu to show if there was no row selected. No row selected means there is no "blue frame" around the row when you click on it, the table view might have 3 rows of data but the click might happen outside the rows, therefore making selected row = -1, already posted a working answer I figured out. The duplicate was about a specific cell and not row

Comment: The "blue frame" is the clicked row. Selected rows have a blue background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pretty easy:

Implement

`NSMenuDelegate`

and add this method:

```
func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        if myTableView.selectedRow < 0 {
            menu.cancelTrackingWithoutAnimation()
        }
    }
```